# How to create new columns with groupBy and transform from rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'MONTHYEAR' : ['2021/01', '2021/02', '2021/03', '2021/01', '2021/02', '2021/03', '2022/01'], 
    'CATEGORY'  : ['INCOME', 'INCOME', 'INCOME', 'INCOME', 'INCOME', 'INCOME', 'INCOME'], 
    'SUBCATEGORY': ['INCOME HD', 'INCOME HD', 'INCOME HD', 'INCOME AD','INCOME AD','INCOME AD', 'INCOME AD'],
    'AMOUNT': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000]
})
```

I want to add 3 new columns HD, AD and SUM

```
df3['HD'] = 0
df3['AD'] = 0
df3['TOTAL'] = 0

df3['TOTAL'] = df3['AMOUNT'].groupby(df3['MONTHYEAR']).transform('sum')

df3.loc[df3['SUBCATEGORY'] == "INCOME HD", 'HD'] = df3['AMOUNT'] 
df3.loc[df3['SUBCATEGORY'] == "INCOME AD", 'AD'] = df3['AMOUNT'] 


df3
```

so far I get this:

[image]

but what I want is this

[image]

Any help much appriciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) first, `rename` columns and create new column by `sum`, last convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df1 = (df3.pivot_table(index=['MONTHYEAR','CATEGORY'], 
                      columns='SUBCATEGORY', 
                      values='AMOUNT', 
                      aggfunc='sum', 
                      fill_value=0)
         .rename(columns={'INCOME AD':'AD','INCOME HD':'HD'})
         [['HD','AD']]
         .assign(TOTAL = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         )
print (df1)
  MONTHYEAR CATEGORY    HD    AD  TOTAL
0   2021/01   INCOME  1000  4000   5000
1   2021/02   INCOME  2000  5000   7000
2   2021/03   INCOME  3000  6000   9000
3   2022/01   INCOME     0  7000   7000
```

Comment: thanks a lot - I should have known this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `.agg()` function.
Here's the code:

```
df3 = df3.groupby(['MONTHYEAR']).agg({'CATEGORY':'first', 'HD':'sum', 'AD':'sum', 'TOTAL':'first'}).reset_index()
```

The output will look like this:

```
    MONTHYEAR   CATEGORY    HD        AD    TOTAL
0   2021/01       INCOME    1000    4000    5000
1   2021/02       INCOME    2000    5000    7000
2   2021/03       INCOME    3000    6000    9000
3   2022/01       INCOME       0    7000    7000
```